# Do propagating electric fields have energy stored in them?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, energy, electric-fields

We know that speed of electric field is C in space, when we place a charge say at location P the electric fields from P travels outward and signal reaches other places later than charge was placed at P.
Which means that $E$-field has velocity.

Does it contain energy too? Cause if it doesn't then it can be a violation to law of conservation of energy in many time dependent situations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the electric field does contain energy. The energy density due to the electric field is given by
$$u=\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}E^2$$
And the energy associated with the electric field is:
$$U=\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}\int_\text{entire field}E^2dv$$

---

For point charge, if you compute this, close to the origin, our integral blows up. That simply tells us it would take infinite energy to pack finite charge into zero volume which is true. Physically, the particle does have finite size. How much energy it takes to make such a particle is a question that goes beyond the  classical electromagnetism.